# Finding all employees that have the first name of James in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm still learning sqlite. How do I find all employees in a table that has the first name of James?

SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name ?

Comment: `= 'James'`, `LIKE '%James%'`, `LIKE 'James_%'` ? Add some rows + the names of the table columns in your post.

Comment: do we assume that you are always storing the full name in this column ?

Comment: You've given us no information on your table. How are we supposed to answer your question? What columns does your table have in it? We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we're sitting; the **only** information we have is what you've posted in your question. If you want our help, **include the information needed** so we can help you.

Comment: Yes the full name is stored in name.

Comment: Sorry, they are id, name, start_year, end_year, pay. My English is not too good.

Comment: The table is employees.

Comment: @Ian , add these details to your question. After a while, the comments will be similar to the second page of Google results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name like 'James %'